# Spinner is not working with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Country from '../Country/Country'

const Countries = () => {
    const[countries,setCountries]=useState([])
    const [isLoading,setLoading]=useState(true)
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
           .then(res=>res.json())
           .then(data=>setCountries(data))
        setLoading(false)

    },[])
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className="row row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-1 g-2 mt-3">
                {
                    isLoading?<Spinner animation='border'/>:countries.map(country=><Country key={Math.random(1,10)} country={country} />)
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Countries;
```

Spinner is working Outside { }.But when I am trying this->

```
{isLoading?<Spinner animation='border'/>:countries.map(country=><Country key={Math.random(1,10)} country={country} />)}.
```

It is not working.I want to say It did not show any spinner before data showing

Comment: You should probably put that in the `useEffect` before the `fetch` - and the perhaps "unset" it after it completes in the last promise .`then(`

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable spinner after response arrive:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
           .then(res=>res.json())
           .then(data=>{
             setCountries(data)
             setLoading(false)
})
```

I suggest you to use only countries state:

```
const[countries,setCountries]=useState(null)
....
!countries?<Spinner animation='border'/>:countries.map(....

    },[])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is less resource-consuming than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You should be logging what `isLoading` is right before the return. You should also put the state change in the final `then` to confirm that there is data and it has finished being retrieved.

```
useEffect(()=>{
 fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
  .then(res=>{
    if (!res.ok){
      console.log(res)
    } else {
      res.json()
    }
  }).then(data=>{
    setCountries(data)
    setLoading(false) // here is the state change
  })
})
```

Comment: and/or if it errors: "a then() handler must check the Response.ok and/or Response.status properties." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I omitted error handling as I would leave it up to OP to determine error handling but I added it to the snippet for clarity.

Comment: Yep, more a comment for the OP here; FWIW `console.log(res)` in production code is generally a bad idea - in some browsers and browser versions this has been known to lock the browser (fail) at that point unless the console is actually open.

Answer (score 0):

First, make setLoading false whenever it gets data:

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    setCountries(data);
    setLoading(false);
  });
}, []);
```

Use a function to render countries for good practise:

```
const renderCountries = () => {
    countries.map((country) => (
      <Country key={Math.random(1, 10)} country={country} />
    ));
};
```

Finally, check isLoading then show spinner other invoke the function to show countries:

```
{isLoading ? <Spinner animation="border" /> : renderCountries()}
```

Comment: Please update your answer to add an explanation of your suggestion to make it an even better answer